# Errors using DacServices to unregister a data tier

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Upgrading my code from DacStore to work in SQL Server 2016 and running into issues with DacServices.  The goal here is to unregister the data tier of a preexisting database before updating the schema.

Code snippet:

```
$serverconnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
If (!$uid -And !$pwd){
   $serverconnection.ConnectionString  = "Server = $server; Database = $database; Integrated Security = True;"
}
Else{
   $serverconnection.ConnectionString  = "server = $server; Database = $database; Integrated Security = False; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"
}

# Load the DAC assembly
$validate = Test-Path $dacfxPath
if (!$dacfxPath){
    throw 'No usable version of Dac Fx found.'
}
Add-Type -Path $dacfxPath # Attempt to load DAC assembly

$DacService = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices($serverconnection)
$dacName  = $database

## Only delete the DAC definition from msdb, the associated database remains active.
$DacService.Unregister($dacName)
```

Error received when creating DacServices object:

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Format of the initialization string does not conform to 
specification starting at index 0."
At C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\_ir_sf_temp_0\UnregisterDataTier.ps1:34 char:15
+ ... acService = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices($servercon ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

My connection string appears correct, and worked in the past.  What else could I be doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Update: Specifying in the DacServices constructor arg that it was a connection string seemed to fix the issue.

```
$DacService = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices($serverconnection.Connec‌​tionString)
```

Having an issue with the Unregister() method now, but one step closer!